# React not rerender when useselector state updated

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I tried to solve this problem the entire day and could not find a solution.

```
const tasks = useSelector((state)=>{
    return state.taskReducer.tasks;
  });

React.useEffect(()=>{
    //....some code

},[tasks])

--------------
<div className='App' style={{
            border: '1px solid',
            marginTop: '5%',
            minHeight: '20em',
            borderBottom: '16px solid',
            borderRight: '12px solid'}}>
              {(tasks === undefined || tasks.length === 0)   ? <></> : 
              tasks.map((task, index)=> 
                    <Taskbar desc={task} key={index} index={index}/>
              )
              }
          </div>
```

So I tried to reorder this task list and render the change, but seems like whatever I do the react does not detect the change.

Here is the code for redux, the **arrange** case would be the one change the object's order.

```
import logger from 'redux-logger';
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import taskReducer from '../reducer/reducer';
import userReducer from '../reducer/userReducer';


export default configureStore({
  reducer: {taskReducer, userReducer},
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) => getDefaultMiddleware({serializableCheck: false}).concat(logger),
  devTools: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production',
});
```

```
const taskReducer = createReducer(initialState, async (builder) => {
  builder
    .addCase(getAll, (state, action)=>{   
      const tasks = [...action.payload];
      tasks.forEach((ele, index)=>{
        ele.index = index
      });
      return {...state, tasks: [...tasks]}
    })
    .addCase(increment, (state, action) => {
      action.playoad.index = state.tasks.length
      const tasks = [...state.tasks, action.playoad]
      return {...state, tasks: [...tasks]}
    })
    .addCase(decrement, (state, action) => {
      try{
        const data = state.tasks.filter(item=>{
            return item._id !== action.payload._id
        })
        return {...state, tasks: data}
      } catch(err){
        console.log(err)
      }
     
    })
    .addCase(editing, (state, action)=>{
      const data = action.payload;
      let tasks = state.tasks;
      for(let i=0; i < tasks.length; i ++){
        if(tasks[i]._id === data._id){
          tasks[i].text = data.text;
          break;
        }
      }
      return {...state, tasks: [...tasks]}
    })
    .addCase(arrange, (state, action)=>{
      const tasks = [...state.tasks];
      const currIndex = action.payload.currIndex;
      const dropIndex = action.payload.dropIndex;
      const curr = {...tasks[currIndex], index: dropIndex, text: tasks[currIndex].text}
      const next = {...tasks[dropIndex], index: currIndex};
      tasks.splice(dropIndex, 1, curr);
      tasks.splice(currIndex, 1, next);
      tasks.sort((a, b)=>a.index - b.index);
      return {...state, tasks: [...tasks]}
    })
    .addDefaultCase((state, action) => {return {...state}})
})
```

I tried a lot of way to return the array without the old reference, it seems like redux has captured the change, here is the state log for redux,

[image]

I tried to add/remove tasks in useEffect, but both did not work.

Comment: I also tried to add properties, it did not work. Then I added a new task, it detected the change, but did not render everything correctly in order.

Answer (score 0):

Using an index as a key can lead to unexpected results. So use key={task._id} instead of key={index}

Comment: Thank for helping Arifur. Unfortunately, I Just tried, still not working.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is here

```
      tasks.map((task, index)=> 
                <Taskbar desc={task} key={index} index={index}/>
          )
```

you have to wrap the `jsx` with () to indicate you are returning `jsx`

```
    (<Taskbar desc={task} key={index} index={index}/>)
```

or

```
 tasks.map((task, index)=> {
             return   (<Taskbar desc={task} key={index} index={index}/>)
          )
```

Comment: sorry man, I just tried not working.

Answer (score 0):

I found out where I got wrong, because I used useState to get one of the props from parent component. So after the props changes, it will not reflect the changes, since the useState was declared on first render.